# Create element in code and use a template to insert it into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a element in JavaScript and inserting it into the dom.

```
 let div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = '<p id="' + selected.val() + '">' + selected.text() + '</p>'; 
document.getElementById('pickedLingua').appendChild(div);
```

Working fine, but the problem is, that when I try to stylize the element, I think this html string will become very hard to read.

Can I maybe create a html template and insert the data into it? There must be a better way then to just create a long html string that no one can read after.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: that doeslook like the exact thing i am looking for. feel free to post this an answer with some clearifications and ill accept it thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create an HTML template and insert the data into it using JavaScript. Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<template id="template">
<div>
 <p id="lingua"></p>
</div>
</template>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Get a reference to the template
const template = document.getElementById('template');

// Create a new instance of the template
const instance = template.content.cloneNode(true);

// Modify the content of the template instance
const linguaElement = instance.querySelector('#lingua');
linguaElement.id = selected.val();
linguaElement.textContent = selected.text();

// Insert the modified template instance into the DOM
const pickedLingua = document.getElementById('pickedLingua');
pickedLingua.appendChild(instance);
```

In this example, we're using the querySelector method to find the #lingua element inside the template instance and modify its id and textContent properties. This will make your code more readable and easier to maintain

Comment: just what I was looking for. awesome!

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to read, you could make the HTML string using backticks.

```js
function myCustomElement(parentSelector, data) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Hello ${data.name}!</h1>
    <caption>This is my custom element!</caption>
    <p style="color: ${data.color}">This text is colored in ${data.color}</p>
   `
   
  const parentNode = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
  parentNode.appendChild(div)
 }
 
 myCustomElement('.container', { name: 'World', color: 'red' })
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```